# How to make this book shelf grid have drag/select features?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

### Introduction

I am writing a toy project as a proof of concept and to push myself. The application is a ASP.NET5 MVC6 library user interface. I want to create a grid representation of a library shelf with dynamic properties, but ***I am completely stuck on this the last two weeks***. The entire thing is open source and you can find what I have done so far [here](https://github.com/HeathWillCode/SampleLibrary).

### Problem

I want the user to be able to drag their finger across my grid to select whatever they want. They could then unselect by the same gesture. The idea is to "check out" books doing this. I am stuck figuring out how to implement my **M3**

In other words, how can I make the DOM object I have created interactive?

Consider the image below. I have 5 mock scenarios.

[image]

**M1**
The most basic situation. I click on shelf and I can see a representation of a 3 x 5 shelf.

**M2**
Red represents occupied position on the book shelf. I want to use the database to get this information and some how show that to the user.

**M3**
Green represents what the user wants to select. I am assuming this would be on a tablet. So I would like them to be able to drag their figure across the screen.

**M4** This is for a scenario that isn't important right now (checking out everything)

**M5**This means that the user can go to different bookshelves and get a different grid. This bookshelf is 3 x 5.

### Accomplished

**M1** This is finished. 
[image]

**M5** This is finished. This is because I have the row and column specified for shelf in my database: 
[image]

So I can draw up the [grid](https://github.com/HeathWillCode/SampleLibrary/blob/master/src/SampleLibrary/Views/Shelf/Details.cshtml) as follows:

```
<div class="grid">
@{ int columnN = Model.columnNumber;}
@{ int rowN = Model.rowNumber;}
@{ int container = 1;}

<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group">
    <!--Select All Button-->
    <button id="toggle-well-all" type="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-table"></i></button>
    @for (int i = 1; i <= columnN; i++)
        {
    <!--Column Header-->
        <button id="toggle-well-column-@i" type="button" class="btn btn-info">@i.ToString()</button>
    }
</div>

@{int a = 0;
        <!--Define the row based on Bin row size -->
    for (int j = 1; j <= rowN; j++)
    {
            <!--Define the row header button -->
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group">
            <!--Row Header-->
            <button id="toggle-well-row-@j" type="button" class="btn btn-info">@j.ToString()</button>

            <!--Well Column-->
            @for (int k = 1; k <= columnN; k++)
            {
                    <!--Well Button-->
                <button type="button" id="select-well-@container" class="btn btn-default bin-well bin-row-@j bin-col-@k" data-toggle="button"></button>
                container++;
            }
        </div>
    }
}
</div>
```

### Notes

In order to make this as clean as possible I am trying to make it the following approach:

- Use C# and Razor to create DOM to represent my bookshelf
- Use what ? to make this DOM to have the interactive features I need
- Once I have the interactive features, I plan on tying it to the database?
- Learning javascript

**Attempts**

- Doing it with javascript first. Bad idea. I couldn't get my javascript to read my Razor and C# code. Also, not best practice. So I am approaching it DOM first now.

Any assistance rendered would be more than appreciated. I am willing to listen and learn. I have worked and failed a lot on this, so reaching out as last ditch effort. Thank you so much for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fairly big question. You are essentially asking how to build a web application full stack. There is no one answer to offer that will solve it for you. So, instead I'll tell you how I would approach the problem in a little detail.

To start we need to break the problem down into simpler things and knock them out one at a time. Since you are using MVC, I will assume the use of the Model View Controller design pattern.

With that in mind, I would start with a model in C#. At a minimum we need a Book and a Shelf type. The Book type would have an availability property. The Shelf would have a set of Books and maybe a Type property that describes the shelf configuration (ie 3x5, 5x7).

Once the model is created, I would then create a fake store that represents my data access layer. This store would have a handful of shelves in it in various configurations with various books.

I would then use the fake store to work on my razor view to simply render a shelf as a table. I personally would use css classes to mark the status of the book in the table and data attributes to identify the book. Keep working here until you can render each of your possible shelf configurations as a table with proper css classes.

The end result table might look something like this:

```
<table id="shelf">
    <tr>
        <td class="book available" data-id="1">Fight Club</td>
        <td class="book checkedout" data-id="2">The Great and Secret Show</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="book available" data-id="3">The Winds of Winter</td>
        <td class="book checkedout" data-id="4">Ready Player One</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Next, I would then start working on client side javascript to detect user interaction events. Maybe start with the touch event on all the books that writes the book id to the browser console. Then refine your event subscriptions so that you can differentiate on the status of the book.

Here is an example with jQuery in case this is not clear what I mean. You might start with some client side script that looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#shelf .book").on("touch", function() {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        console.log(id);
    });
});
```

And then to differentiate the status of a book, you might do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#shelf .book").on("touch", ".available", function() {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        console.log(id + " available");
    });

    $("#shelf .book").on("touch", ".checkedout", function () {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        console.log(id + " checkedout");
    });
});
```

Note: I did not test the above code. So consider it psudo-code that might need some tweaking.

Now that you have event handlers for touch events that get the book id, I would write an ajax call to post the id to a controller action specific to the action I want to take. So for available books, I would post to something like /books/checkout/id. And for checkedout books, post to books/checkin/id. I would stub out the bookscontroller's action methods to simply return a positive response.

In my ajax call success event, I would then swap the css class appropriately. For example, an available book would post an ajax call to /books/checkout/id and on success I would remove the available class and add the checkedout class.

Next, I would work on making my fake store actually store data in a database.

Then, wire up my books controller action stubs to modify that data in the database.

Finally, consider error condition. What happens if I post a book id to the checkout action that is already checked out? What if the book with that id doesn't exist? If I checkout a book, how do other people viewing that shelf know its checked out?

As, you can see I am approaching the problem breaking it into small pieces. And implementing small things that build a bigger thing. I am hopping between the various layers backend, controller, client side ui stubbing as I go and eventually replacing with new code as needed.

But that is not all! Last consider the quality of the code you have. Attempt to remove any duplication (especially if it is duplicated 3 or more times). Look at the names of all your variables, classes and methods, do they accurately represent what is going on? Remember variable, class and method names can be as long as you want make them descriptive. What has more meaning "var x" or "var bookId"?

Basically what I am saying is refactor for brevity and clarity. Your 6 month older self will thank you when you come back to try to edit this code.

Don't get me started on unit tests....

Good luck.

Comment: This is probably the best reply I have ever gotten on stack overflow.